# How to send email with attachment by postfix from command-line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, email, postfix

I've just setup a new Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server on linode for myself. Followed an excellent instruction at: [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.10-maverick-meerkat-ispconfig-2-p5) to finish the installation of some basic stuff including postfix.

I am trying to figure out a way to send an email to my gmail address with an attachment, but cannot find how. Already confirmed that email can reach my gmail account.

In the end I have to use mutt to send the email with attachments, probably [SendEmails](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) will also do well, but I am wondering how to do the same thing in postfix from command-line?

Many thanks in advance for this dumb question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why does it have to be `postfix` directly? `mailx -a`, `mutt`, or `mutt -a` will also use the `sendmail` interface -- unless *you* configure them for SMTP.

```
echo "This is a test message" | mutt -s Test -a foo.zip -- $USER
```

```
echo "This is a test message" | mail -s Test -a foo.zip $USER
```

(Note, in bsd-mailx the option is `-A` instead.)

---

Anyway, here's a "postfix" example.

Replace `$USER`, content type and filename to match your environment. Example assumes you are sending the message to yourself and have a ZIP file `foo.zip` in the current directory.

```
(printf "%s\n" \
    "Subject: test" \
    "To: $USER" \
    "Content-Type: application/zip" \
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.zip" \
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" \
    "";
 base64 foo.zip) | sendmail "$USER"
```

*(Creation of MIME multipart messages left as an exercise to the reader.)*

Comment: `mail -a foo.zip` does not attach `foo.zip` to a message as with `mutt`.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: depends on `mail`, I guess. It does so in heirloom-mailx.

Answer (score 8):

Postfix is a [mail transfer agent (MTA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent). Its job is to handle the delivery of the mail: pick it up and send it to the next point on its route. Postfix is a postal worker, whose job is to take an envelope and (with help from its colleagues) carry it to the recipient.

What you're asking for here is secretarial work: assembling documents to put them in the envelope. That's not Postfix's job: it's a job for a [mail user agent (MUA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent). You can write a crude MUA that just assembles pieces to make a mail in a few lines of shell, as [grawity did](https://superuser.com/questions/220913/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-by-postfix-from-command-line/221040#221040), but Mutt is really a good tool for this task.

Answer (score 6):

From the command line, I like to use "sendemail", which on ubuntu / debian can be installed from the command line like so:

```
apt-get install sendemail
```

Then you can simply tell it to use localhost (Postfix) as the MTA.

Actually I just noticed that localhost:25 is the default:

```
-s SERVER[:PORT]          smtp mail relay, default is localhost:25
```

You then add attachments using the -a flag:

```
sendemail -f sender@example.com -t recipient@example.com -m "This is the message" -u "This is the subject" -a file1.zip file2.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

[**mailx**](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) 12.4 has an option for attaching files:

> `-a` *file*
>        Attach the given file to the message.

For example:

```
[gawad@centos Desktop]$ mail -s "pine" -a pine.rpm.gz root@localhostEnter
this is the pine software you asked forEnter
.Enter
EOT
[gawad@centos Desktop]$
```